# Perl's Regular Expression in a Tibetan Script

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove/delete the second last character of a Tibetan script, as shown below (character in following example are of English):

```
$char = "ti.be.tan.|";
```

So I want to remove the "second last" character  "."  I tried in following way with my few knowledge of RE:

```
$char =~ s/.|$/|/g;
$char =~ s/[.|]$/|/g;
$char = tr/.|//d;       # and later add |.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Before I tell you what you need to do right, let's look at what you're doing wrong:

```
$char =~ s/.|$/|/g;
```

The problem here is that both `.` and `|` are *metacharacters* in regular expressions. The `|` means "or", so you're saying "match `.` or `$`". You correctly know that `$` means the end of the string, but `.` means "any one character." So it immediately matches one character, and continues to immediately match one character, each time changing that character to `|` (metacharacters don't apply in the second half of the `s///` expression), then it matches the end of the string and adds a `|` in there. Or something like that. Basically, not what you want to happen.

```
$char =~ s/[.|]$/|/g;
```

Well, inside `[]`s, `.` and `|` stop being metacharacters, but `[]` means "one of these," so this regular expression looks for the character before the end of the string, and if it's either `|` or `.`, it changes it to `|`. Again, not what you want to happen.

```
$char = tr/.|//d;       # and later add |.
```

`tr` is the wrong tool for this job. This would delete all `.` and `|` characters in your string, expect that you're not using the `=~` regex match operator, but the `=` assignment operator. Definitely not what you want to happen.

What you want is this:

```
$char =~ s/\.\|$/|/;
```

We've escaped both the `.` and the `|` with a `\` so Perl knows "the character after the `\` is a literal character with no special meaning*" and matches a literal `.|` at the end of your string and replaces it with just `|`.

That said, it sounds like you're kind of new to regular expressions. I'm a big fan of [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), which I think is one of the best (if not *the* best) introduction to regular expressions in Perl. You should really read it - regexes are a powerful tool in the hands of those who know them, and a powerful headache to those who don't.

Comment: Thanks... Both "." and "|" are not the character you are referring to.
I gave those two as an example of "Tibetan unicode charater 0F0B(.) and OFOD(|).  Thanks for pointing me to perl's documentation.

Comment: You'll probably need to use Unicode escapes to get the same effect. I don't know Tibetan, but I bet the `perldoc` regular expression pages will discuss this issue at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Chris Lutz has already provide an excellent answer so I just want to provide additional answer in case you want to remove second last character of other kind of string.

Here it is:

```
$char =~ s/(.)(.)$/\2/g;
```

Basicaly, Perl (actally RegEx) will map everything between '(' and ')' to groups. Which you can manipulate that group later. From this code the gourps are.

```
$char =~ s/(.)(.)$/\2/g;
#          ^-^^-^  ^^
#  Capture G1 G2   ++-- Then replace it with only group 2
```

So in this case, Perl goes from the first character, since it was not match any, it let go (not replace), when it find a match it replace the match with what you specified (in this case is group#2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `\2` escapes are deprecated, and will generate a warning if you `use warnings;` (which I'm sure you always do :P). You should use `$2` instead.

Comment: to clarify, they are deprecated on the right side of s///, not the left.

Comment: Oh really?!! :-o I always use it because I first use it in sed. :p

Comment: Why two sets of brackets? Matches don't need to be captured to be replaced.
$char =~ s/.(.)$/$1/g; would be just as effective.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `substr` as an lvalue in this situation:

```
$char = "ti.be.tan.|";
substr($char,-2,1) = "";
print $char;               # ===>  ti.be.tan|
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also the method using positive lookahead assertion to remove the second last character.

```
$char ~= s/.(?:.$)//;
```

Which essentially reads substitute "" for any character which is immediately followed by a single character and the end of the string.

If the second last character is always a specific character you can replace the first . Remember to escape RE metacharacters ()[]/.*?